# Upload de arquivo para uma pasta dentro da pasta raiz com PHP

Tags: php

Baseado no código de documentação do PHP sobre fileupload criei o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = './novo/side';
$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.\n";
  } else {
 echo "Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!\n";
}

   echo 'Aqui está mais informações de debug:';
   print_r($_FILES);

   print "</pre>";

?>
```

Até ai tudo bem, quando eu uso o form do HTML ele pega o arquivo e traz para a Raiz do projeto, o problema é que eu quero que ele vá para uma pasta que está dentro da raiz chamada `side`.

```
$uploaddir = './novo/side';
```

O resultado que tenho é que o arquivo fica apenas na pasta `novo`.

Nos testes liberei o compartilhamento herdado para que não tivesse impedimento de acesso as pastas.

Estou usando Windows com WampServer.

Comment: Tentei essa já mas não da certo também, ele continua mandando para a raiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na função `move_uploaded_file` você está movendo ele para:

```
$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
```

Então o correto, no seu caso seria:

```
$pasta = $uploaddir."/".$uploadfile;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $pasta)
```

Comment: Então pelo que entendi incluiria a linha `$pasta = $uploaddir."/".$uploadfile;` e a linha de `move_uploaded_file` ficaria dessa forma `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $pasta)) {`. Tentei e não deu certo.

Comment: Tipo assim isso é um exemplo para vc entender o processo, o código é seu vc não precisa acrescentar está nova variável, mas vc tem de entender como o script tá trabalhando... Se vc colocar como sugerido pelo MArcelo:
`$uploadfile = $uploaddir."/".basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])` aí vc não precisa dessa nova variável `$pasta`... O importante para seu aprendizado e vc ver como o script percorre cada linha e o que ele faz... Boa sorte man :) qualquer duvida vai comentando...

Comment: Ai um ponto interessante. eu tinha entendido que se eu coloco `$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`dessa forma tenho apenas o acréscimo do nome da pasta no nome do arquivo e com isso continua indo apenas para a raiz.

Comment: Mas vc precisa da `/` então fica : `$uploadfile = $uploaddir."/".basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'])`, sacou?

Comment: Me desculpe a falta de entendimento, comecei a estudar agora e entendi que estava faltando `/` ele compõe o final do endereço, porém agora estou com um problema de acesso a pasta no Windows. Vou resolver por aqui.

Comment: Isso ae... Boa Sorte qualquer dúvida não hesite a criar uma nova questão, se alguma das respostas estiver correta, considere validá-la clicando no incon verde  em baixo das setas de avaliação.